# I formatted /sdcard and my phone won't boot

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop, formatting

I have a Samsung Galaxy Star Duos GT-S5282. I installed ClockworkMod Recovery 5 and I was messing with it. I went to "mounts and storage" then chose `format /sdcard` and then rebooted the system.

It is stuck on the logo and restarting and isn't loading. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you quite sure you didn't select `format /system` instead by accident?  Did you have a custom ROM installed as well?  If so, simply re-flashing the ROM image (and optionally gapps) should bring the phone back to normal.

Comment: That is what I try but Odin3 is now about 4 hours flashing it and it didnt finish yet, is that normal?! @Chahk

Comment: No, definitely not normal.  Flashing via Odin usually takes a few minutes.  Try disconnecting the phone, re-connecting it and flash again.

Comment: And it will not get bricked on unplugging it during the process? @Chalk

Comment: Well, it can't get any worse than it already is.  If Odin's been stuck for 4 hours, it's not going to finish at all.  Most likely it hasn't even started the flashing process at all.  Also, in order for Odin to even recognize your phone, it needs to be in Download mode, not Recovery.

Comment: @Chahk Yes my phone is in Download Mode and I am using Odin 3 v3.09 and flashing the stock ROM,the log says:
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> boot.img
<ID:0/004> recovery.img
<ID:0/004> SPRDCP.img
<ID:0/004> cache.img
<ID:0/004> system.img
It took about 15 mins for each img and I am using unoriginal cable, may that be a reason for the delay? Honestly, I am very afraid to unplug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you delete the whole system on your device, so that there is currently no rom to boot.
What you can do now is to flash a rom. If you have an external SD card slot, then push your rom files and g-apps onto it and insert the card and flash via recovery.
If your device does not have an external SD card slot or you do not have one, you have to flash the rom via adb. Here's a link to that: [xda-Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Flashing_Guide_-_Android#ROM_update_without_SDcard)
I hope I understood you correctly and that it helps

Comment: I am currently trying to flash it using Odin but its now about 4 hours and its still progressing, is that normal?!

Comment: I assume you already have a custom recovery installed, right? If so, I would not try to flash via Odin, but it's more than 1 year since I last used Odin, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: You need to flash a custom recovery in Odin. This should take about 5 seconds. Then you can use the recovery to flash your ROM. Alternatively you could Odin flash a Stock ROM (http://sammobile.com) which should only take a couple of minutes max.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your phone is soft bricked. Try re-partitioning it with the pit file and flashing the original stock firmware. This will not take 4-hours.